# Using cursor to loop through a table variable in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a parameter of a stored procedure which gets some data in the format

```
1/1/2018-2/1/2018,2/1/2018-3/1/2018,3/1/2018-4/1/2018,4/1/2018-5/1/2018,5/1/2018-6/1/2018,6/1/2018-7/1/2018,7/1/2018-8/1/2018,8/1/2018-9/1/2018,9/1/2018-10/1/2018,
10/1/2018-11/1/2018,11/1/2018-12/1/2018,12/1/2018-12/31/2018
```

I have a function which splits the data based on the `,` character and stores the results into a table variable as shown here:

```
declare @SPlitDates table(ItemNumber int, Item nvarchar(max))

insert into @SPlitDates
    select * 
    from dbo.SPlitFunction(@RequestData, ',')
```

After this I have to perform certain operations on the data range so I use cursors to loop through the temp table as shown below

```
DECLARE cur CURSOR FOR 
     SELECT Item 
     FROM @SPlitDates 
     ORDER BY ItemNumber

OPEN cur

FETCH NEXT FROM cur INTO @monthStart

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0 
BEGIN
     -- Some operation
END
```

The max data points that I will get in the temp table is the date range for 12 months.

My question is that could I be using something else apart from cursors to improve performance or it doesn't matter when the dataset is really this small.

Thanks

Edit - To show operation inside the cursor

```
declare @SPlitDates table(ItemNumber int, Item nvarchar(max))

insert into @SPlitDates
    select * 
    from dbo.SPlitFunction(@RequestData, ',')

declare @SPlitDatesData table (ItemNumber varchar(100), Item nvarchar(max))
declare @SPlitDatesAvgData table(Code nvarchar(100), Val decimal(18,2))
declare @dataFilter as nvarchar(max),
        @SQL as nvarchar(max);

declare @monthStart nvarchar(100)
declare @count int

set @count = 0

--Declaring a cursor to loop through all the dates as defined in the requested quarter
DECLARE cur CURSOR FOR 
     SELECT Item 
     FROM @SPlitDates 
     ORDER BY ItemNumber

OPEN cur

FETCH NEXT FROM cur INTO @monthStart

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0 
BEGIN
    DECLARE @Period NVARCHAR(100)
    SET @Period = @monthStart

    INSERT INTO @SPlitDatesData
        --split the dates to get the start and the end dates
        SELECT * 
        FROM dbo.SPlitFunction(@Period, '-')

    DECLARE @PeriodStart NVARCHAR(100)
    DECLARE @PeriodEnd NVARCHAR(100)

    SET @PeriodStart = (SELECT Item FROM @SPlitDatesData WHERE ItemNumber = 1)
    SET @PeriodEnd = (SELECT Item FROM @SPlitDatesData WHERE ItemNumber = 2)

    DELETE FROM @SPlitDatesData

    --add the start and end dates to the filter
    SET @dataFilter = 'StatusDate between convert(datetime,('''+@PeriodStart+'''))  
    and DATEADD(dy, 1, convert(datetime,('''+@PeriodEnd+''')))'

    SET @count = @count +1;
    SET @SQL = 'INSERT INTO #BidAverageCycleCalculation (SortOrder, Code, Data)
                VALUES (@count,
    ''SL Payroll'',(select dbo.GetAverageCycleBetweenBids('''+@PeriodStart+''',
    '''+@PeriodEnd+''',''SL''))
     )'

    EXEC SP_ExecuteSQL @SQL, N'@count int', @count;

    SET @count = @count +1;
    SET @SQL = 'INSERT INTO #BidAverageCycleCalculation (SortOrder, Code, Data)
                VALUES (@count,
    ''GV Payroll'',(select dbo.GetAverageCycleBetweenBids('''+@PeriodStart+''',
    '''+@PeriodEnd+''',''GV''))
     )'

    EXEC SP_ExecuteSQL @SQL , N'@count int', @count;

    SET @count = @count +1;

    SET @SQL = 'Insert into #BidAverageCycleCalculation (SortOrder,Code,Data)
  Values (@count,
    ''Global Payroll'',(select dbo.GetAverageCycleBetweenBids('''+@PeriodStart+''',
    '''+@PeriodEnd+''',''GVS''))
     )'

    EXEC SP_ExecuteSQL @SQL, N'@count int', @count;

    SET @count = @count +1;

    SET @SQL = 'Insert into #BidAverageCycleCalculation (SortOrder,Code,Data)
  Values (@count,
    ''TimeHCM'',(select dbo.GetAverageCycleBetweenBids('''+@PeriodStart+''',
    '''+@PeriodEnd+''',''Time''))
     )' 

    EXEC SP_ExecuteSQL @SQL, N'@count int', @count;    

    delete from @SPlitDatesAVgData  

    FETCH NEXT FROM cur INTO @monthStart
END

CLOSE cur    
DEALLOCATE cur
```

Comment: First, declare your cursors as FAST_FORWARD unless you absolutely cannot.

Second, whether you can use a solution other than cursors depends a great deal on what that "-- some operation" entails. What exactly is going on in the body of your loop? If you're having to call a stored procedure per line, then cursors may be your best or even only option. If it's something else, there might be a set-based operation that is more efficient. But we can't know unless we know what's going on in there.

Comment: So inside the --some operation I basically am using the date that I get from the FETCH NEXT FROM cur INTO @monthStart to fill up some temp tables based on the date range..I only use the cursor to loop through the table variable and get the dates inside it.

Comment: You should post that logic. Sounds like there could be a translation from that to a set-based operation that doesn't use cursors at all, but we'd need to see it to know for sure.

Comment: I added the code...This is just one of the code I am using..I am using the same  cursor logic in other SP's as well which do some other kind of of operation

Comment: From what you posted I don't see any need for a cursor or dynamic sql. This seems to be a lot more complicated than it needs to be.

Comment: Yeah I guess for this I can remove dynamic SQL..I am using the same cursor logic at other SP's where I have dynamic columns selected based on dates for which I was using Dynamic SQL.

Comment: I added Fast_Forward as suggested and cleaned up the procedure to not have dynamic SQL since not needed..Thanks Guys

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This uses two parts - first convert your string into a table, then do bulk inserts into your destination. No need for cursors.

** Please excuse any syntax errors as I'm doing it without access to your actual tables or functions so cant test it, but you get the idea

```
declare @in varchar(max)
set @in= '1/1/2018-2/1/2018,2/1/2018-3/1/2018,3/1/2018-4/1/2018,4/1/2018-5/1/2018,5/1/2018-6/1/2018,6/1/2018-7/1/2018,7/1/2018-8/1/2018,8/1/2018-9/1/2018,9/1/2018-10/1/2018,10/1/2018-11/1/2018,11/1/2018-12/1/2018,12/1/2018-12/31/2018'

declare @xml xml;
set @xml= convert(xml,'<r><f>'+replace(replace(@in,',','</t></r><r><f>'),'-','</f><t>') +'</t></r>')

declare @t table(id int identity, f date, t date)
insert @t
select 
    Tbl.Col.value('f[1]', 'date') f, 
    Tbl.Col.value('t[1]', 'date') t
FROM  @xml.nodes('//r') Tbl(Col) 

select * from @t

declare @count int;
select @count=count(*) from @t

INSERT INTO #BidAverageCycleCalculation (SortOrder, Code, Data)
select id, 'SL Payroll',(select dbo.GetAverageCycleBetweenBids(f,t,'SL')) from @t

INSERT INTO #BidAverageCycleCalculation (SortOrder, Code, Data)
select id+@count,'GV Payroll',(select dbo.GetAverageCycleBetweenBids(f,t,'GV')) from @t

INSERT INTO #BidAverageCycleCalculation (SortOrder, Code, Data)
select id+@count*2,'Global Payroll',(select dbo.GetAverageCycleBetweenBids(f,t,'GVS')) from @t

INSERT INTO #BidAverageCycleCalculation (SortOrder, Code, Data)
select id+@count*3,'TimeHCM',(select dbo.GetAverageCycleBetweenBids(f,t,'Time')) from @t
```